# Mongo Doctrine Query Builder Select does not work. Bug?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-orm

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');

$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:Listing')
            ->select('title')
            ->field('coordinates')->geoNear(
                  (float)$longitude, 
                  (float)$latitude
            )->spherical(true);

$classifieds_array = $classifieds->toArray();

$data = array('success'=>true,'classifieds' => $classifieds_array, 
      'displaymessage' => $classifieds->count(). " Search Results Found");
```

Even though I am selecting just one field, for my result set, I am getting every thing back in collection along with title. Is this a bug?

**NOTE**: I commented out the `->field('coordinates')->geoNear((float)$longitude, (float)$latitude)->spherical(true)` line and now the select seems to work. This is crazy.

Comment: I believe this is because of the way that a `geoNear` command runs: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand Maybe doctrine is a bit confusing here in showing how the query is really formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [geoNear](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand) command in MongoDB doesn't seem to support filtering result fields, according to the documentation examples. Only a `query` option is supported to limit matched documents.

In your case, it also looks like mixing up the `geoNear()` and `near()` builder methods in Doctrine. Since you're operating on the `coordinates` field, the appropriate syntax would be `near()`. `geoNear()` is a top-level method to tell the builder you wish to use the command, which doesn't require a field name since it uses the one and only geospatial index on the collection.

For usage examples, I would advise looking at the [query and builder unit tests](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/tree/master/tests/Doctrine/MongoDB/Tests/Query) in the Doctrine MongoDB library.